# Which TTL Property should a browser respect where you use a CNAME record?

Tags: dns, server, ttl

We have an application thats domain has a CNAME record. Then that domain has an A record. What happens if these 2 records have different TTL properties? For example.

```
NAME                   TYPE   VALUE                TTL
----------------------------------------------------------------------
bar.example.com        CNAME  foo.example.com      3600 (60min)
foo.example.com        A      192.0.2.23           30   (30sec)
```

In this example if I hit bar.example.com how long will the IP address be cached on the browser for? I noticed in chrome it will cache the IP address for up to 30sec, but i'd imagine different browsers could have different implementations. I would like to know if there is a standard way this should be implemented or if there are any browsers that would use the 60min record. I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special handling of TTL for CNAME resource records. In a perfect world, the browser should remember each record according to its TTL.

That is, if a new CNAME for `bar.example.com` that pointed at `baz.example.com` was published, the browser could still use the old one pointing at `foo.example.com` for up to 3600 seconds. At all times, it could not remember the IP address associated with the name `foo.example.com` for more than 30 seconds.

While I haven't tried to check, I suspect that many implementations are not that picky, and my guess would be that it's common use the TTL of the final A record for the entire `bar.example.com` -> `192.0.2.23` step.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. The reason why I think that some browsers are using the 60min record is because we are using AWS EC2 instances in an auto scale group. they are not behind a load balancer so we have all of their public IP addresses in the DNS record. when we scale up we are noticing that it is taking a while for the load to balance across the new servers. Now that I think about it, it could have something to do with the new record taking some time to propagate across all dns servers.